# Perl sendmail to list is truncated

Tags: perl, cgi, sendmail

I am working with a perl based cgi pages for a webproject. I am encountering a strange problem with `sendmail` module which happens randomly.

Problem:
 Sendmail would truncate the emails of the users appended at last. But not always, it happens randomly. I log the email list right before sending email and I don't see anything wrong.

Example Image (See Karl's last name is truncated at '.' after his first name.)

[image]

Headers for the email.

```
  Message-ID: <201305221503.r4MF3dYf022792@pazmo.internal.company.com>
  Subject: < ...>
  MIME-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/plain
  To: <biradavolu.ln@company.com>, <dessimira.ln@company.com>,
  <yun.ln@company.com>, karl.
 Date: Wed, 22 May 2013 10:03:39 -0500
 From: <tool@company.com>
 Return-Path: tool@company.com
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: eusaamw0712.domain.company.com
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 10
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: MSFTFF;1;0;0 0 0
```

The logged input before sending email: ( I don't see anything wrong with the format)
        biradavolu.ln@company.com;dessimira.ln@company.com;yun.lastName@company.com;karl.LastName@company.com;

```
use Mail::Sendmail;

# Step 1: Declare the mail variable
%mail = (
    from => 'test@company.com',
    to => 'user1FN.user1LN@company.com;user2FN.user2LN@company.com;user3FN.user3LN@company.com;' . "$requester_email; $responsible_email",
    subject => ... ,  
    'content-type' => "multipart/alternative; "
);

my $toList='user1FN.user1LN@company.com;user2FN.user2LN@company.com;user3FN.user3LN@company.com;' . "$requester_email;";   

# Step 2: Add members to toList based on different conditions
if(condition1)
    $toList= $toList.'user4FN.user4LN@company.com;';
if(condition2)
    $toList= $toList.'user5FN.user5LN@company.com;';

... # few other similar condition statement
...

# Step 3: Assign toList based on different conditions
$mail{ 'to' } = $toList;

# Step 4: Set Body of the $mail
if(sendmail(%mail)){
    print LOGFILE "Mail send successfully to $mail{\"to\"}:  ";
}else{
    print LOGFILE "Mail was not send : Mail list was $mail{\"to\"}  : ";
}
```

Comment: Rather than a screen shot, could you post the relevant header from the message's source?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the header information now

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here.  You're hiding the actual lastnames of your users (which is fine), but it could be possible that the "random" truncating is always happening on a user with a space in the last name?  Like "St. Pierre".  Your string might get truncated right at the space.

Let me know if that's possible!

Comment: it a good guess but no I don't have users with space in last name.